# Change a CSS property value with jquery only when it has a certain function

Tags: jquery, css

I want to use jQuery to change a CSS property value but only if the property has a certain function.

For example:
`[class="btn"] { background-image: linear-gradient(red, white)`  }

I only want to set background-image to none when it has the function linear-gradient. I dont want to change it in any other case.

Thank you very much!!!

Comment: read the bacground image and test its content

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could get the value for the `background-image` and then test it against `linear-gradient(red, white);`:

```
var element = $('[class=“btn”]'); // or just $('.btn');
if(element.css('background-image') == 'linear-gradient(red, white)') {
    // do something
}
```

Or maybe just check against `linear-gradient` so it will match no matter which colors are used by the gradient;

```
var element = $('[class=“btn”]'); // or just $('.btn');
if(element.css('background-image').indexOf('linear-gradient') == 0) { // == 0 to check if the background-image starts with linear-gradient
    // do something
}
```

Comment: That seems pretty nice. And if I want to check every single object in the DOM, I guess that an array would work. I will try it. Thank you very much.

Comment: @CabezachumboSampedro it’s the same. If you have multiple `.J` use the same code. JQuery will hook the events to all of them using the same sentence.